# Error in using 'ddply' and 'glm' for k-value estimation (hyperbolic delay discounting) in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, plyr, glm

I am trying to find the most suited k-value (or discount rate) that best explains my participants' choices for immediate vs delayed reward (where lower k value means they choose a lot of immediate options and higher k value means they are more "patient".)

**SS** = Smaller Sooner; **LL** = Larger Later Reward; **Delay** = in Days; **Choice** = 0:SS, 1:LL; **SV** = Subjective Value.

So first I assign 5001 potential k values or discount rates to each trial (from -50 to 200 in steps of 0.05) which results in a data frame with 8001600 rows (50 participants * 32 trials per participant * 5001 potential values).

This is how the k-values were assigned to the data -

```
    uniquek<- c(seq(-50,200,0.05))
    DataSoc <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(uniquek),function(i) data.frame(i,SocialData))) 
    k <- rep(uniquek, times = nrow(SocialData))
    DataSoc$k <- k
```

Then I create an empty data frame (called 'data_simulation' here) with 3 columns (PPN_f, k, r_squared) each 8001600 rows long.

Then I try to apply 'ddply' to a data frame to be able to perform a logistic regression using glm, something like this -

```
    data_simulation <- ddply(DataSoc,.(PPN_f,k), function(x){
    r_squared <- summary(glm(Choice ~ SV_diff, x, family=binomial()))$r_squared
    return(data.frame(r_squared))}, .progress ="win")
```

Ideally, this would give me the r_squared values for each trial, after which I would find the k with the largest r_squared value for each participant, and assign the corresponding k-value to that participant.

**BUT** the regression just isn't going through. Could you help solve this issue?

Here's the first 6 rows of my raw data for reference. Thank you for your help!

```
    > head(SocialData)
    PPN_f (Participant as factor)  SS   LL   Delay  Choice SS_SV LL_SV SV_diff
        <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
      1 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000 30000    60      1  1000   1000      0
      2 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000  5000    60      0  1000   1000      0
      3 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000 10000    60      1  1000   1000      0
      4 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000  5000    30      0  1000   1000      0
      5 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000  5000     5      1  1000   1000      0
      6 5e7339dac6b16528d49937bc  1000  2500    14      0  1000   1000      0
```

Comment: Where is `k` in your data?

Comment: That is  added later to the raw data, but before regression. Each row you see above in the raw data is replicated 5001 times, with k values such as -50, -49.95, -49.9, -49.85...199.5, 200 assigned to them.

Comment: Could you please try next code on your real data? Code: `data_simulation <- ddply(DataSoc,.(PPN_f,k), function(x){
  y <- glm(Choice ~ SV_diff, x, family=binomial())
  r_squared <- with(summary(y), 1 - deviance/null.deviance)
  return(data.frame(r_squared))}, .progress ="win")`

Comment: Thanks! It went through, but gives me 50+ warnings of "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 0"

In the 'data_simulation' dataframe, I get r_squared values until row #245049 but then the rest are all -Inf. 

Any suggestions on how this glm function can be optimized further?

Comment: It depends on the model you choose. I would try other kind of model otherwise the actual model you have is not working well!